# Wrong week number in ISO 8601 date in SQL Server Analysis Services

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssas, iso8601

According to ISO 8601, the first week of the year is the week with the year's first Thursday in it. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date#First_week.

Unfortunately, SQL Server Analysis Services (SQL Server 2008) seems to have a bug in the ISO 8601 date implementation, since week 1 starts at January 1st, 2010 and not (as it should) at January 4th.

Is that assumption right? Does anybody know anything about that problem?

Answer (score 0):

I know little, but Michael Kaplan knows more http://www.siao2.com/2005/11/14/492249.aspx "ISO 8601 is asinine"  But I don't know if that provides any solution.  He talks on the subject frquently BTW.

Comment: If I understand this blog post, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michkap/archive/2010/10/03/10070787.aspx, there is no possibility for a real ISO 8601 date, currently.

Answer (score 0):

You can always create a date dimension table in your DW or use the one created by TI wizard, update the table in DW and then use it as the source for your time dimension.
I always create my own date/time dimensions.

HTH,
Hrvoje